# Use output of an algorithms with another algorithm in QGIS Graphic Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have Processing Algorithm of Explode Lines and I need to use the output of the layer to create a field calculator Processing Algorithm, so i have entered the filed name that i need to create and type also the expression of this field which is
array_length(
overlay_equals(
'Exploded_Lines',$id
)
) + 1
like this
[image]
so the result of graphical modeler was
[image]

now when I run my model which is in the picture below
[image]
I'll get this error
[image]

Comment: If I remember a similar question correctly it is supposed to be `@Explode_lines_OUTPUT` or something similar, it is a variable available.